# Converting left padded String to number

Tags: java

In Java 6, if I have a `String` of length 11 which contains a negative number that is left padded with zeros and I want to convert it to a `Long`, how do I go about doing this?

```
String x = "000000-3946";

try {
    Long.parseLong(x)
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

...throws a `NumberFormatException`.

By removing the leading zero is the only way for me to get this to work. I've tried to parse using the `NumberFormat` and `DecimalFormat` classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd statment will remove all the preceding zeros by using **regular expression**  and giving you a valid string which can be parsed to Long value. (handles both positive and negative numbers)

```
String x = "000000-3946";
String xWithoutLeadingZeros = x.replaceFirst("^0+", "");
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(xWithoutLeadingZeros));
```

---

From comments:

The above code `replaceFirst` will actually creates Pattern object internally for every call.

```
//code of String.replaceFirst
return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceFirst(replacement);
```

Since we are using this method for large number of inputs, creating pattern object every time is not the correct way, as the regEx is same for all inputs.

So we will create pattern object only once, hope it gives much better performance result.

```
private static final Pattern leadingZeroPattern = Pattern.compile("^0+");
private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "-232330000809";
    String xWithoutZeros = leadingZeroPattern.matcher(x).replaceFirst(EMPTY_STRING);
    System.out.println(Long.parseLong(xWithoutZeros));
}
```

#perfmatters

Comment: If the String was "-1234567809" would the Zero be replaced?

Comment: Yes of course. only leading zeros will be removed. Try if you doubt it.

Comment: Also I feel, parsing number string which has leading zero, will lead into ambiguous. because number preceded with zeros are considered as octal numbers. So if we trim the string correctly, everything will work fine and looks fine.

Comment: Thanks, I have about a few hundred million records to transform. I needed a good efficient way and think this will be the way.

Comment: If you are handling such many records, then use the updated one. I hope it gives better performance result. Also I recommend you to try, other ways and note down the time taken and update if you get better result.

Answer (score 1):

First, [`Long.parseLong(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) can throw [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). Next, I'd check for a minus sign, and if present take a substring from that position. Something like

```
String x = "000000-3946";
int p = x.indexOf("-") > -1 ? x.indexOf("-") : 0;
try {
    long l = Long.parseLong(x.substring(p));
    System.out.println(l);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outputs

```
-3946
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit overkill, but this will do the trick:

```
final String x = "000000-3946";
int start = x.indexOf("-");

System.out.printf("%s%n", Long.parseLong(x.substring((start > -1) ? start : 0, x.length())));
// ...or just
//System.out.printf("%s%n", Long.parseLong(x.substring((start > -1) ? start : 0)));
```

**OUTPUT**: `-3946`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single line, try this:

```
 Long.parseLong(x.replaceAll("0+-", "-"))
```

And to add about your second question, if string is -1234567809, no zeros to be replaced here